# How to view your data from your database into "A" views and "B" with same data in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, codeigniter

hello guys i have a little problem here, anyone can help me?
i need to view my data from database in "A" view, but in another case i want to view it too in "B" view.

this is the model of "A" view

```
function m_fetch_country(){
    $query=$this->db->query('SELECT country_name FROM uhd_country');
    return $query->result();
}
```

and this the controller of "A" view

```
            $data['country']=$this->Product_m->m_fetch_country();
            $this->load->view("/MAIN/Personal",$data);
            $this->load->view("/MAIN/Header",$data);
```

anyway i have success view the data it on "A" view. but i cant view it on "B" view. this "B" view has different controller and model file from "A" view.

so what should i do to view the same data in "A" and "B" view?
i just want to call the country name in my database into "B" view for the registration field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fetch the data from same model function and pass into your "B" view page

```
$data['country']=$this->Product_m->m_fetch_country();
$this->load->view("b_view",$data);
```

You can call data as `$country` in your view page.